# htaccess get parameters for seo url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

// Sorry for the grammar mistakes and any other thing that's wrong, English isn't my mother tongue(don't know if I spelled it good).

I have made SEO friendly URLs with htaccess. The only problem is, that I always would get information out the url(using GET) and now with the SEO friendly URLs I can't do that.

My previous url was this:

```
http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem?id=2
```

So in PHP it would be $_GET['id'] and it would be 2. But now that I've got SEO friendly urls it's this:

```
http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem/2/
```

And now my PHP script can't see where he would get the ID from, so it will return me back to the homepage.

I have Googled that you need to use (.*) in htaccess but I don't know where or how.
My htaccess code is this atm:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/rasolutions\.eu\/" [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule    ^blog/(.*)([0-9]+)/$    blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^blogitem/(.*)([0-9]+)/$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two rules should be correct *without* that `(.*)` according to the example syntax you posted. And you have to take care of the trailing slash (`/`) in a flexible manner:

```
Options +MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# WWW to not WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rasolutions\.eu$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rasolutions.eu$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]*)/?$        blog.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogitem/([0-9]*)/?$    blogitem.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

In general it is a *very* good idea to use RewriteLogging if you have access to it. It helps you understand exactly what is going on inside the rewriting engine at each single sub step instead of having to *guess* what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry but this still won't fix the problem. The PHP script still doesn't know where to get the id from, how can I specify in htaccess that after blog/ the page will come.

Comment: Sure it will. `$_GET['id']` (`$_GET['page']`) will hold whatever was specified after the last slash (`/`) in `http://rasolutions.eu/blogitem/2`... That is the whole point of such rewriting! You just have to make sure those two lines really do match the request, so actually are applied!

Comment: That said: are you _really_ sure those example urls you gave _really_ end in a trailing slash? Why?

Comment: I'm sorry but it still doesn't have a difference. When I use http://rasolutions.eu/blog/2/ it won't do it and when I do http://rasolutions.eu/blog/2 it won't do it.

Comment: "it won't do" is not a valid problem description. What does that mean? No rewriting takes place? You get an error? The universe implodes?

Comment: It won't rewrite it by it self, but also if I go to the url the PHP script will tell me that there is not id specified. Thank you for helping.

Comment: For rewriting: please comment out the other rules for testing purposes. About the arguments inside php: well, if you request a php script with a query parameter like `?id=5` and you then do _not_ have a variable `$_GET['id']` with value 5 inside that script then sorry, either something is _really_ borked on your system or you did not test correctly.

Comment: If I go to blogitem?id=5 it will show me the blog item, but if I go to blogitem/5/ or to blogitem/5 it will not show me the blog item. That's the problem I have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51051/discussion-between-arkascha-and-rezam)